# Show X Axis and align to y axis range in Gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

i'm trying to create a violin plot with some data in gnuplot.
The issue i'm facing is that the x axis is not plotted, only xtics are shown, and it also seems that the axis is not aligned with the bottom of the y range.
I tried to play with xtics command and with set zeroaxis but I wasn't able to solve the issue.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
set terminal svg size 1920,1080
set output "pic.svg"

set print $viol0
        y = 0.24
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.48
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.28
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.56
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.52
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.32
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        unset print
set print $viol1
        y = -0.24
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = -0.16
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = -0.44
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = -0.28
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = -0.28
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = -0.56
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        unset print
set print $viol2
        y = 0.0
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 1.0
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.5833333333333344
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.5000000000000009
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.7499999999999996
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.08333333333333348
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        unset print
set print $viol3
        y = 0.3333333333333336
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.5999999999999998
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.5999999999999998
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.6666666666666664
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.6999999999999997
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.5666666666666671
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        unset print
set print $viol4
        y = 1.2999999999999996
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.8499999999999999
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.975
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.7999999999999999
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.8499999999999999
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.7749999999999999
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        unset print
set print $viol5
        y = 2.8666666666666694
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.6000000000000024
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 1.0666666666666682
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.9333333333333347
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.8666666666666665
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        y = 0.733333333333333
            print sprintf(" 0.0 %8.5g", y)
            
        unset print
set title 'Overview'

set border 2
set xrange [33:36]
set xtics ("A" 34, "B" 35)
set xtics nomirror scale 0
set ytics nomirror rangelimited
unset key
set style data points

set linetype  9 lc "#800072b2" ps 0.5 pt 5
set linetype 10 lc "#8033bbbb" ps 0.5 pt 5


# set title "Same data - kernel density"
set style data filledcurves below
set auto x
unset ytics
set border 3
set margins screen .15, screen .85, screen .15, screen .85
set key

set table $kdensity0
plot $viol0 using 2:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.15 with filledcurves above y lt 9
unset table
set table $kdensity1
plot $viol1 using 2:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.15 with filledcurves above y lt 9
unset table
set table $kdensity2
plot $viol2 using 2:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.15 with filledcurves above y lt 9
unset table
set table $kdensity3
plot $viol3 using 2:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.15 with filledcurves above y lt 9
unset table
set table $kdensity4
plot $viol4 using 2:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.15 with filledcurves above y lt 9
unset table
set table $kdensity5
plot $viol5 using 2:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.15 with filledcurves above y lt 9
unset table
unset key

set border 2
unset margins
set ytics nomirror rangelimited

set style boxplot nooutliers
set style fill solid bo -1
set boxwidth 0.075
set errorbars lt black lw 1

set xrange [-0.5 :(6-0.5)]
set xtics autofreq 1
set yrange [-1:2]

plot \
     $kdensity0 using (0 + $2/200.):1 with filledcurve above x=0 lt 9,\
     '' using (0 - $2/200.):1 with filledcurve below x=0 lt 9,\
     $viol0 using (0):2 with boxplot fc "white" lw 2,\
     $kdensity1 using (1 + $2/200.):1 with filledcurve above x=1 lt 9,\
     '' using (1 - $2/200.):1 with filledcurve below x=1 lt 9,\
     $viol1 using (1):2 with boxplot fc "white" lw 2,\
     $kdensity2 using (2 + $2/200.):1 with filledcurve above x=2 lt 9,\
     '' using (2 - $2/200.):1 with filledcurve below x=2 lt 9,\
     $viol2 using (2):2 with boxplot fc "white" lw 2,\
     $kdensity3 using (3 + $2/200.):1 with filledcurve above x=3 lt 9,\
     '' using (3 - $2/200.):1 with filledcurve below x=3 lt 9,\
     $viol3 using (3):2 with boxplot fc "white" lw 2,\
     $kdensity4 using (4 + $2/200.):1 with filledcurve above x=4 lt 9,\
     '' using (4 - $2/200.):1 with filledcurve below x=4 lt 9,\
     $viol4 using (4):2 with boxplot fc "white" lw 2,\
     $kdensity5 using (5 + $2/200.):1 with filledcurve above x=5 lt 9,\
     '' using (5 - $2/200.):1 with filledcurve below x=5 lt 9,\
     $viol5 using (5):2 with boxplot fc "white" lw 2
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is the reason that you create your datablocks `$viol` so complicated? Simply type `$viol1 <<EOD` `0.24` ... `EOD`. Or can't you put it into a single file/datablock with 6 columns?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply and your welcome.
I've created the datablocks that way because I'm generating this script with jinja2 from a python program i'm triyng to convert from matplotlib to gnuplot, and this was the simplest way I found to insert data directly in the script.
However I will try to change my template to use this simpler and more readable syntax you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you copied from different gnuplot script examples without knowing what the commands are doing. Well, you have to start somewhere. For every command there should be a help entry. In gnuplot console, simply type `help <yourKeyword>` and you will get more information.

A few answers to your questions and comments to your script:

- x-axis is not plotted because you told gnuplot to do so (`set border 2`). Check `help border`
- y-axis "gap" because you told gnuplot to do so (`set ytics rangelimited`). Check `help ytics`.
- your way to create a datablock looks horribly complicated to me. Maybe, there is a reason for it, but compare with the script below.
- if your are plotting to a table (the fillstyle and color doesn't matter). And setting a new table will unset the previous one.
- in your case the violin plot is covered by the boxplot. So, simply introduce a scaling factor to scale the width of your violin plot.
- you can shorten some commands or keywords `using` vs. `u`, `with` vs. `w` to make your script shorter and increase readability.

Check the minimized script below. It certainly has room for further improvements.

**Script:**

```
### violin and box plot
reset session

$viol0 <<EOD
0.24
0.48
0.28
0.56
0.52
0.32
EOD

$viol1 <<EOD
-0.24
-0.16
-0.44
-0.28
-0.28
-0.56
EOD

$viol2 <<EOD
0.0
1.0
0.5833333333333344
0.5000000000000009
0.7499999999999996
0.08333333333333348
EOD

$viol3 <<EOD
0.3333333333333336
0.5999999999999998
0.5999999999999998
0.6666666666666664
0.6999999999999997
0.5666666666666671
EOD

$viol4 <<EOD
1.2999999999999996
0.8499999999999999
0.975
0.7999999999999999
0.8499999999999999
0.7749999999999999
EOD

$viol5 <<EOD
2.8666666666666694
0.6000000000000024
1.0666666666666682
0.9333333333333347
0.8666666666666665
0.733333333333333
EOD

set table $kdensity0
    plot $viol0 u 1:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.15
set table $kdensity1
    plot $viol1 u 1:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.15
set table $kdensity2
    plot $viol2 u 1:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.15
set table $kdensity3
    plot $viol3 u 1:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.15
set table $kdensity4
    plot $viol4 u 1:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.15
set table $kdensity5
    plot $viol5 u 1:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.15
unset table

set title 'Overview'
set border 3
unset key
set linetype  9 lc "#800072b2" ps 0.5 pt 5
set linetype 10 lc "#8033bbbb" ps 0.5 pt 5
set style boxplot nooutliers
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.075
set errorbars lt black lw 1

set xrange [-0.5 :(6-0.5)]
set xtics nomirror
set yrange [-1:2]
set ytics nomirror # rangelimited

W = 0.025   # scaling factor for violin width

plot \
     $kdensity0 u (0 + $2*W):1 w filledcurve above x=0 lt 9,\
             '' u (0 - $2*W):1 w filledcurve below x=0 lt 9,\
         $viol0 u (0):1 w boxplot fc "white" lw 2,\
     $kdensity1 u (1 + $2*W):1 w filledcurve above x=1 lt 9,\
             '' u (1 - $2*W):1 w filledcurve below x=1 lt 9,\
         $viol1 u (1):1 w boxplot fc "white" lw 2,\
     $kdensity2 u (2 + $2*W):1 w filledcurve above x=2 lt 9,\
             '' u (2 - $2*W):1 w filledcurve below x=2 lt 9,\
         $viol2 u (2):1 w boxplot fc "white" lw 2,\
     $kdensity3 u (3 + $2*W):1 w filledcurve above x=3 lt 9,\
             '' u (3 - $2*W):1 w filledcurve below x=3 lt 9,\
         $viol3 u (3):1 w boxplot fc "white" lw 2,\
     $kdensity4 u (4 + $2*W):1 w filledcurve above x=4 lt 9,\
             '' u (4 - $2*W):1 w filledcurve below x=4 lt 9,\
         $viol4 u (4):1 w boxplot fc "white" lw 2,\
     $kdensity5 u (5 + $2*W):1 w filledcurve above x=5 lt 9,\
             '' u (5 - $2*W):1 w filledcurve below x=5 lt 9,\
         $viol5 u (5):1 w boxplot fc "white" lw 2
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Here is a version where you have your input data all in one datablock (or file) but in different columns. Then you can use a loop for all columns. If you plot your `kdensity` into a table using a for-loop, you will get different sub-blocks which are separated by two empty lines. If you want to plot that data you can address the sub-blocks via `index` (check `help index`).

**Script:**

```
### violin plots with a loop
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# viol0   viol1   viol2   viol3   viol4   viol5
0.24    -0.24   0.0     0.333   1.299   2.866
0.48    -0.16   1.0     0.599   0.849   0.600
0.28    -0.44   0.583   0.599   0.975   1.066
0.56    -0.28   0.500   0.666   0.799   0.933
0.52    -0.28   0.749   0.699   0.849   0.866
0.32    -0.56   0.083   0.566   0.774   0.733
EOD

set table $kdensity
    plot for [i=0:5] $Data u i+1:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.15
unset table

set title 'Overview'
set border 3
unset key
set linetype  9 lc "#800072b2" ps 0.5 pt 5
set style boxplot nooutliers
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.075
set errorbars lt black lw 1

set xrange [-0.5 :(6-0.5)]
set xtics nomirror
set yrange [-1:2]
set ytics nomirror

W = 0.025   # scaling factor for violin width

plot for [i=0:5] $kdensity index i u (i + $2*W):1 w filledcurves x=i lt 9,\
     for [i=0:5]        '' index i u (i - $2*W):1 w filledcurves x=i lt 9,\
     for [i=0:5]     $Data         u (i):i+1 w boxplot fc "white" lw 2
### end of script
```

**Result:**

Although the result should be the same as the graph above, I don't understand yet why the violin plot looks different (in this one not all violin-plots are cut in y-direction). Maybe somebody else can explain.

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.
As you correctly guessed I started copying parts from the demos available on gnuplot's  site and I got lost in the documentation without understanding correctly the program.
The datablock is made that way because it was the simplest method I found to insert data in the script and that I was able to put in a jinja2 template to make plots directly from a python program I'm trying to migrate from matplotlib to gnuplot.
However I will try to apply your suggestions to fix my script and make it better.
Thanks again for your answer.